# APY PAYPAL IPN NOTIFICATION

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

I made a website `ASP.NET MVC` which use PAYPAL to manage payments.
I want to know when the payment is received by paypal account and save the information into my database.

The situation is the following:
TWO OR MORE USERS

- USER_A has product which want to sell
- USER_A subscribe an account in my Website,
- USER_A provides is paypal email account to my website
- USER_B SEES USER_A'S PRODUCT
- USER_B WANTS TO BUY IT
- USER_B MAKE ORDER IT
- USER_B PAY BY PayPal
  to do that I have followed the instruction from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/)

everything works good, although there a problem,
to get the notification of payment into my website the USER_A (who receives the payment) 
has to enable IPN notification into his paypal accaunt and set URL for  notification.

Could be nice avoid that the user does that manual and make a automatic procedure to do that, my achievement is

- USER_A SUBSCRIBES AN ACCAUNT  INTO MY WEBSITE
- USER_A PROVIDES HIS PAYPAL ACCOUNT
- USER_A CLICK A BUTTON AND HIS PAYPAL ACCOUNT GET IPN SETTING INFORMATION BY A "PAYPAL API"

Is that possible? I spent so much hours into paypal API info websites but I haven't found anythings valuable. Is there anyone who as manage that  problem?

thanks

michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update somebody's profile setting via the API, but you can include the NOTIFYURL parameter in your API request and that would simply override what is in the profile.

You could even setup a listener that you host and have your application send all the IPN's to it so that you can generate personalized email notifications, update your database, hit 3rd party web services, or anything else you might want to automate for your customers.

You could actually go ahead and give your sellers the option to setup an IPN URL that they want to use separate from what you're sending in NOTIFYURL so they can do their own processing, too.  Then you would actually POST the same IPN data from your listener on to their listener.  I actually wrote an article on this awhile back you might be interested in:  [Daisy Chaining IPNs](http://go.developer.ebay.com/content/daisy-chaining-ipns)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks to reply.
I have already overridden the NOTIFYURL to redirect the IPN to
a page which works as listener and update my database and that works fine.

So you say that definitively I cannot enable IPN of customers 
by APY?

The big problem is that every customer has to do that setting and 
the way to do it  into Paypal is a bit tedious.

I will try to edit my first question, if my first question cannot be done there any other way to know when the payment is got?

Hope to not be to much confused in my question :-\

thanks 
michele

Comment: Since you're using NOTIFYURL that would override any setting in the merchant's profile anyway, so even if they did do it nothing would go to their IPN URL. I'm editing the answer now to provide another potential option for you.

Comment: You are right that overridding NOTIFYURL will override what the user has written into his profile, but it will not override the flag option which enables the IPN, since IPN to be used needs the  option enable valued true and the NOTIFYURL. 
My hope was properly to set the value of Enable option = true by API

Comment: In my experience notifyurl works regardless of whether or not IPN is actually enabled in the profile.

Comment: I have just tryed one more time and I have to say you are right, NOTIFYURL overrides any setting in the merchant's profile anyway, 
I really do not know what happened in my first tests, sure I did a mess when nothing worked and I managed wrongly the problem.
anyway Thanks for your suggestions which force me to try again and discover that the solution was under my nose :-D

have a good coding

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  If you have a moment I'd appreciate you marking the answer to give me some points.  :)